# white border for popup on blackberry

Tags: blackberry, popup, border

I want to add a white border for popup screen on blackberry.
I use this code to add the border

```java
Popup x = new Popup();
Border borderFocus = BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(new XYEdges(10, 10, 10, 10), 0xffffff, Border.STYLE_SOLID);
x.getDelegate().setBorder(borderFocus);
```

///////////////////class Popup/////////////////////

```java
public class Popup extends PopupScreen {

    public Popup() {
        super(new VerticalFieldManager(), Field.FOCUSABLE);

        HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(
                Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH | FIELD_VCENTER);
        HorizontalFieldManager hfmBtn = new HorizontalFieldManager(
                Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH | FIELD_VCENTER | FIELD_HCENTER);


        LabelField title_screen = new LabelField("ddd");
        title_screen.setPadding(11, 5, 0, 0);
        hfm.add(title_screen);


        add(hfm);
        add(new SeparatorField());

        add(new LabelField(""));
        final LabelField labelVersion = new LabelField("ffffffffffffff");

        ButtonField btn_cancel = new ButtonField(
                "cancel");


        ButtonField btn_ok = new ButtonField("Yes");

        btn_ok.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 60);
        add(labelVersion);

        hfmBtn.add(btn_cancel);
        hfmBtn.add(btn_ok);
        add(new LabelField(""));
        add(hfmBtn);

    }

    public void sublayout(int width, int height){

        super.sublayout(width,height);

        setPosition(35,65);

    }
    public boolean onClose() {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen();

        return true;

    }
```

But I get the border into the popup and no a white border for the window of popup.

[image]

Comment: can you post your `Popup` class, as that's not a built-in BlackBerry UI class?   thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I add it. Can you check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the **easiest** way to solve the problem, but it works for me.

Basically, the default border for the `PopupScreen` is causing problems.  Even if you changed your code from:

```java
x.getDelegate().setBorder(borderFocus);
```

to

```java
x.setBorder(borderFocus);
```

it doesn't look right (there is a rectangular frame outside your rounded border).

So, what I basically did is this:

1. Make the default `PopupScreen` border and background completely clear/transparent.
2. Override the `paintBackground(Graphics)` method in the `Popup` class, and manually draw the solid color background, and then the rounded corner white border.

So, add this to your `Popup` class:

```java
   public class Popup extends PopupScreen {

      protected void paintBackground(Graphics g) {
         int oldColor = g.getColor();
         
         // we'll have to draw in the background, since we blanked it in
         //  the constructor
         g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
         int arcWidth = 20;
         g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), arcWidth , arcWidth);
         // and now, draw in the border manually
         g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
         g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), arcWidth , arcWidth);
         
         g.setColor(oldColor);
      }

      public Popup() {
         super(new VerticalFieldManager(), Field.FOCUSABLE);

         // make the screen's default border/background completely transparent
         setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(Color.BLACK, 0));
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(new XYEdges(), Border.STYLE_TRANSPARENT));
         // use some padding to compensate for getting rid of the screen's default border
         int pad = 10
         setPadding(pad, pad, pad, pad);

         /** The rest of the constructor is as you originally had it */
```

And then you can remove these lines:

```java
Border borderFocus = BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(new XYEdges(10, 10, 10, 10), 0xffffff, Border.STYLE_SOLID);
x.getDelegate().setBorder(borderFocus);
```

because that's done manually in the `paintBackground()` method now.

### Results

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nate.I used your method.

Comment: @mobileDeveloper, you're welcome.  Note that I posted an update to my original answer.  I believe that in the original answer, the corner radius was off by a factor of 2.  If you use the updated code, it should be closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, there's an undocumented method you need to override on PopupScreen, in order to eliminate the black border on a popup screen.  That's `applyTheme` -- just implement it with an empty body to avoid the black border, then your own setup should work the way you expect.

```
protected void applyTheme() {

}
```

Comment: Interesting to know about this method, but when I try it, I [get this result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fRmUn.png).  Alternatively, if I override `applyTheme(Graphics, Boolean)`, the results are different, [but still not right](http://i.stack.imgur.com/huEFK.png).

Comment: Looks like you lose all theming.  I'm not using PopupScreen anymore, but when I was, all the fields contained were custom, so theming didn't affect them.  I don't think this is so workable then, unless you have full use of custom fields.